# Display string among themselves

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

With the help of my BackEnd API I get a string, for example the `response` is :

```
test.sh has been executed by Java,test.sh has been executed by Java,test.sh has been executed by Java
```

I want to split the string at `","` and show each item among each other. It should look like this:

```
1. test.sh has been executed by Java
2. test.sh has been executed by Java
3. test.sh has been executed by Java
```

Until now it looks like this:

```
1. test.sh has been executed by Java,test.sh has been executed by Java,test.sh has been executed by Java
```

Heres my frontend:

```
<template>
<v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-card
          class="mt-15 pa-4  mx-auto"
          max-width="700"
          color="#BDBDBD"
          text = "red darken-1"
      >
        <ol>
          <li class="white--text" v-for="item in output" :key="item">{{item}}</li>
        </ol>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
    </v-form>
    </template>
    <script>
     export default {
     data: () => ({
items: [],
search: null,
key: '',
output: [],
}),
 methods: {
  async displayTerminalLog() {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8091/api/v1/output/'
    let response = await this.axios.get(apiUrl);
    console.log(response.data.toString())
    for (var text in response.data.toString().split(",")){
      this.output.push(response.data[text].slice(0, 
      response.data.toString().length-1))}
  }
}
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: So what's not working? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`For…in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will loop over the keys of an object. `split(…)` returns an Array, your need [`for…of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) Try this…

```
for (var text of response.data.toString().split(",")){
// …
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = response.data.toString().split(",");
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    console.log((index + 1) + '. ' + item )
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.